# Empty column on SSRS Excel Extract

Tags: reporting-services

How would I get rid of the empty redundant column on the first column (A) of an SSRS excel report extract?  please see jpg for details (link below).

I want the table to start at cell A4.

Microsoft SSRS seems to automatically set the table to start at cell B4..?

[image: empty column jpg]

Comment: Is your table flush left? `Left = 0`

Answer (score 1):

If you want to start your ssrs Excel export file to start as A1 you need to get rid of everything (header, textboxes, etc..) expect the tablix. Then move your tablix in the report designer to the most left and most top position. If you tablix doenst have merged cells your Excel export should now start at A1 and for every tablix column you will have one Excel column.